# Smooth animation (video) from png images

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I can't make a video file out of my images because I need to keep the transparency of the png files.

I want to get 25 frames per second without delay.

1000+ images 1920x1080 from 8 KB to 5 MB

How can I achieve this ?

Here below are examples that I tried:

**1 example:**
The inhibition of the picture because uploading images.

```
int counter = 0;
DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();

public Png()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 40);
   dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
   dT.Start();
}

void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\" + counter + ".png"));
   imageBox.Source = image;
   counter++;

   if (counter == 1000)
   {
     dT.Stop();
   }
}
```

**2 example:**
Very much clogged RAM because of the large number of files. And, too, are felt drag.

```
    int counter = 0;
    DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();
    private BitmapImage[] images;

    public Png()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       images = new BitmapImage[1000];

       for(int i = 0 ; i < images.Length; i++)
       {
          images[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\" + i + ".png"));
       }

       dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 40);
       dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
       dT.Start();
    }



   void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      imageBox.Source = images[counter];
      counter++;

      if (counter == 1000)
      {
        dT.Stop();
      }
   }
```

**3 example:**

I tried to use a `Queue`

`Queue` tried to use as a buffer of pictures.
First I uploaded 10 pictures to the `Queue`.
Showed first picture.
And as soon as I showed the second picture, I removed the first one and added the eleventh one from the other thread to the `Queue`.

But I got the impression that I was doing wrong, also felt braking, many times corrected the code and eventually accidentally deleted.

Comment: are you using blend keyframes for this?

Comment: Did you try creating GIF? You can use it as an image

Comment: @Tofik I can't make a GIF out of it-the original weight of all PNG 5+ GB - I need a frame-by-frame animation of PNG

Comment: @Tofik I tried buffering in a separate thread (I wrote example 3) - but I accidentally deleted it (- there were friezes too

Comment: This smells like an xy problem, you want a video, but you dont want a video *scratches head*

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes, you're right, I need the video, but the video has a transparent background :)

Answer (score 0):

I will post the modifications to Example 2 as I think it is more efficient, I also encourage you to experiment it with Example 1.

Add one more image box to the form and make sure both image boxes have the same positions and size.

```
void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (counter % 2 != 0) {
         imageBox1.Source = images[counter];
         imageBox1.Visible = true;
         imageBox2.Visible = false;
      }
      else {
         imageBox2.Source = images[counter];
         imageBox2.Visible = true;
         imageBox1.Visible = false;
      }
      counter++;

      if (counter == 1000)
      {
        dT.Stop();
      }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything(((

Comment: Did you try to change DoubleBuffer property of the control to true?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I needed. (

Answer (score -1):

//For FrameRate add this in your XAML .

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                 From="1.0" To="0.5" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="25" />
```

Keyframe Animation is possible in WPF. Add all images in your storyboard by inserting Keyframes for each Image. Keyframes looks like Diamond shapes in your timeline. You can add them manullay in Objects and Timeline.

//Smooth Animations

> ```
>           <!-- Animate the TranslateTransform's X property
>                from 0 to 350, then 50,
>                then 200 over 10 seconds. -->
>
>           <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
>             Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedTranslateTransform"
>             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
>             Duration="0:0:10">
>             <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
>             <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="350" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
>             <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="50" KeyTime="0:0:7" />
>             <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="200" KeyTime="0:0:8" />                          
>           </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
>         </Storyboard>
>       </BeginStoryboard>
>     </EventTrigger>
>   </Rectangle.Triggers> 
> </Rectangle>
> ```